# how to check any open pull request in GitHubs?

Tags: github, pull-request

I got a coding challenge from a company and they require to complete a project on https://www.hatchways.io/

I already completed all of the code, but as I submit it shows that

{ Before you submit the Front-end Work Simulation - Hatchways Times project, you will need to pass the following pre-checks:

You must have an open pull request. ❌

You do not have multiple pull requests opened. ✅

Sorry, looks like you didn't pass all the pre-checks above. Please make sure you satisfy all the requirements before you retry. }

I have two branches one is 'main' another one is 'practice'. I already checked I don't have any pull request both of branches.

Is there anyone know how to solve it please?

[Pull Request](https://i.stack.imgur.com/m5on8.png)

[record of pull request](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pZwSd.png)

Answer (score 0):

1. Click `New pull request`
2. Set the branch to `practice` and the base branch to `main`
3. Submit

Comment: Hi Nick, I follow your instruction it shows that 
There isn’t anything to compare.
main is up to date with all commits from practice. Try switching the base for your comparison.

Comment: Are you working with a fork of one of their repositories?

Comment: I'm not sure. I gave the hatchways.io permission then it automatically creates a repo for me.

Comment: Can you link to the repository?

Comment: After checked my repo, I believe it generate from my account, because I went to my repo section(webpage) and it showed the repo there just like my other repo which I create before

Comment: Even I can change repository visibility to public.....

Comment: Thanks, please let me know when you make it public.